# How to add custom style from _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) function?

Tags: magento2, dynamic-rows

I have added a color picker in dynamic rows using below code:

```
protected function _prepareToRender() {
$this->addColumn(
'color_code,
[
'label' => __('Color Picker'),
'renderer' => $this->getColorRenderer(),
]);
}
private function getColorRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->colorRenderer) {
            $this->colorRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blocks\Edit\Tab\ColorRenderer::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->colorRenderer;
}
```

class ColorRenderer is as given below

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blocks\Edit\Tab;

class ColorRenderer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = '<input type="text" name="' . $this->getInputName() . '" id="' . $this->getInputId() . '" ';
        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var $el = $("#'.$this->getInputId().'");
                        // Attach the color picker
                        $el.ColorPicker({
                            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                                $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
                </script>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Now I can see the color picker and data is getting saved in database.

[image]

Now in the dynamic row section I want to set the background color to the saved value. I know we can use `_prepareArrayRow` function to modify content.

```
protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        if (isset($row['color_code'])) {
            $color = $row->getColorCode(); // getting hex code from dv
         // how to add style here like style="background-color:#FF0000;"
        }
}
```

Now how to set the background color for the existing rows using saved color code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it may work, it is untested code,Just a hint to help you achieving it. You may have to replace the property `backgroundcolor` to `color` or `background-color` as per your need and need to check further what is exact property name.

```
protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        if (isset($row['color_code'])) {
            $color = $row->getColorCode(); // getting hex code from dv
            $row->setData('backgroundcolor', $color);
         // how to add style here like style="background-color:#FF0000;"
          //$row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);

        }
}
```

Comment: Tried with color or background-color and unfortunately it has not added color. I thing there should be some approach to get current element and add style to that.

Comment: I want to get deep drill into this code, so that using anydesk we may fix it, may you please call me at 7895270333 or whatsapp ?